# How to know if the date is in past?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a field called "date2" in my table users. it's like this: "2014-06-01"
i need to check if this date is in past. I tried to do this, but its not working

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date2 FROM users");
$json = array();    
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     $date=$r;
     if (time() > strtotime($date)) {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET seat1='p',seat2='p',seat3='p',seat4='p',request_pass='p',payed=0 WHERE date2='$r'");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `strtotime($date)`? Try some troubleshooting.

Comment: See normalization. (And sql injection/deprecated apis/prepared statements, etc)

Comment: `$date=$r` should be `$date=$r["date2"];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to update all users who have a `date2` value that is in the past (*e.g.* expired) you can do that in just one query:

```
UPDATE users 
SET seat1='p',seat2='p',seat3='p',seat4='p',request_pass='p',payed=0 
WHERE date2 < CURDATE()
```